# Set (or pause) a looping anim to the end keyframe

Tags: javascript, css, keyframe, css-animations

Is it possibe to stop an **infinitely looping** animation at the end keyframe or to set the animation to the end keyframe?

I have an animation that I want to play again and again but be able to pause it after each iteration **precisely** at the end keyframe.

I thought this would be easy by just pausing the animation with

```
animatedElement.on(
    "animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration oanimationiteration MSAnimationIteration",
    function () {
        animatedElement.css({
            "-moz-animation-play-state": "paused",
            "-o-animation-play-state": "paused",
            "-webkit-animation-play-state": "paused",
            "animation-play-state": "paused"
        });
    }
);
```

But the problem is that when tha animation is paused it has **already** begun on the **next** iteration. Thus, in practice, the animation is not stopped at the end keyframe but at the beginning of the next animation iteration.

In other words, in the animation beneath, the animation does not stop on 100% (90deg) but it stops some short time after the animation has already started from 0% (0deg) again.

```
@keyframes rotateAnim {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/taz0k/ppgbA/#base)

Comment: Why not have animation-iteration-count : 1 and later reset the animation ?

Comment: Maybe that would work. If I understand it correctly though the way to reset an animation seems to be quite hacky. http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/ and the "reflow method" only seems to work on Chrome

Comment: For me personally the better way (but this is a matter of opinion) would be Oli Studholme method (cited in your link), the first one, where you have 2 animations identical, but with different names, and you just swap the class.

Comment: Thanks! I have now changed the code to remove and re-add the animation class to repeat the animation instead of using animation-iteration-count: infinite. Now it works.